# How to calculate data from table SQLite Android Dev

Tags: android, sqlite

How to calculate data from table SQLite in Android Dev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "calculate data"

Do you mean normal operator like +,-,*,/

If yes, you have to SELECT the data from SQLite first.

If no, please clarify your question.

Comment: calculate sum of data in row

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp